# DRF docs how to change schema

Tags: django-rest-framework, documentation

I was following a [tutorial](https://github.com/wsvincent/rest-framework-tutorial), I followed the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/#built-in-api-documentation) to add the documentation, but some of the titles are read, read_0, read_1, and I don't know where to change the parameters or the description of those.

For example one of the endpoints is /snippets/delete{format} and the title is read, why is not delete? And I also wanted to take out {format} but don't know how to do it.

Maybe they are too basic questions, but I couldn't find a tutorial or a guide to modify this fields, and I thought maybe the problem was more of how the tutorial program views.py?